# remove or update add_image_size

Tags: images

I'm working on a theme that has a number of image sizes defined correctly using:

```
add_image_size( 'name', 500, 200, true );
```

I would like to override these defined sizes from the child theme:

```
add_image_size( 'new-name', 400, 300, true );
```

I know I can add new sizes, but if I add the same name i.e:

```
add_image_size( 'name', 400, 300, true );
```

Then the parent function call is used - the child one is ignored - adding extra rules adds extra images which will never be used - it's not so bad, but it's not efficient.

Is there a function to de-register an added image size?

Cheers!

Ray

Comment: Can you please post the *entire* code that is relevant? Are the `add_image_size()` calls just sitting nakedly in `functions.php`, or are they properly wrapped inside a callback, and hooked into `after_setup_theme`? Knowing which is critical to answering your question.

Comment: hi chip - thanks for your comment - you're right it's wrapped in after_setup_theme - so this is all about priorities again - I always miss that!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [**`add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop )`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) function is graceful enough to handle multiple calls using the same `$name`. It simply [overwrites the existing value](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/media.php#L185):

```
$_wp_additional_image_sizes[$name] = array( 'width' => absint( $width ), 'height' => absint( $height ), 'crop' => (bool) $crop );
```

So that means that all you need to do to override the parent Theme's definition of the custom image size is to ensure that *your call to `add_image_size()` fires **after** the parent Theme's call*.

Assuming that the Parent Theme does like so:

```
function parent_theme_setup() {
    add_image_size( 'name', 500, 200, true );
    add_image_size( 'new-name', 400, 300, true );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'parent_theme_setup' );
```

Then the parent Theme's `add_image_size()` call fires at the `after_setup_theme` hook, at the default priority (i.e. `10`).

(Note: if the calls are *not* wrapped in a callback, then they fire at the `plugins_loaded` hook, at priority `10`.)

Here's the critical part: **the child Theme's `functions.php` file is parsed *before* the parent Theme's**, so if you use the same hooks to fire your `add_image_size()` calls, they'll get overridden by the parent Theme's `add_image_size()` calls.

The solution is to *use a later hook or a lower priority*, to ensure that the child Theme's `add_image_size()` call fires *after* the parent Theme's.

This should do the trick, regardless of how the parent Theme fires its calls:

```
function child_theme_setup() {
    add_image_size( 'name', 400, 300, true );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'child_theme_setup', 11 );
```

Note that we use the same `after_setup_theme` hook, but use a *lower priority* (i.e. `11` instead of `10`. Callbacks fire in order from higher priority (lower number) to lower priority (higher number), starting with priority `0`. So a callback hooked into priority `11` will fire *after* a callback hooked into priority `10`.

Note also that the `after_setup_theme` hook itself fires *after* the `plugins_loaded` hook, so this callback will still override the parent Theme, even if the parent Theme is `_doing_it_wrong()` by not wrapping such calls in an appropriate callback, hooked into an appropriate hook.

Comment: excellent - thanks chip! - I had them both on the same priority - notched the child back after the parent and all working fine.

Comment: I can't seem to overwrite the value if a plugin is calling add_image_size :(

Comment: took a long time to find this answer.  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If someone wants to simply unset the additional image sizes, as opposed to changing the dimensions, use [remove_image_size( string $name )](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_image_size/), e.g.

```
function pinboard_child_theme_setup( $sizes) {

    $image_size_names = array('thumbnail', 'medium', 'large',
        'slider-thumb', 'blog-thumb', 'teaser-thumb', 'gallery-1-thumb',
        'gallery-2-thumb', 'gallery-3-thumb', 'image-thumb', 'video-thumb');

    $image_size_names_length = count($image_size_names);
    for($x = 0; $x < $image_size_names_length; $x++) {
        remove_image_size($image_size_names[$x]);
    }   
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'pinboard_child_theme_setup', 11);
```

Answer (score -1):

In your chile theme you would need to use 
`add_action( 'after_setup_theme','new-name');`

Comment: new-name here is the name of function or what ever name you are using for your main function

Comment: Add an explanation to your answer: why and how does it solve the problem? Note that `new-name` is an invalid callback name.

Comment: "new-name" is simply the handle of the image size being added.