# Overwrite Parent Theme add_image_size in Child Theme

Tags: functions, theme-development, child-theme, images

I'm using a child theme of a parent theme. Now on my parent theme, theveloper adds some custom image sizes like this -

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) )
    {
        add_image_size( 'blog_feat_img', 1300 );
        add_image_size( 'latest_posts_widget_feat_img', 720 );
        add_image_size( 'portfolio_widget_feat_img_1x', 600 );
        add_image_size( 'portfolio_widget_feat_img_2x', 900 );
    }
```

Now I want to change the values is set default in my partent theme's `functions.php` so searched Google and use every single alternative suggested there.

Starting with this:

- [remove or update add_image_size](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74934/remove-or-update-add-image-size),
- http://www.studiograsshopper.ch/code-snippets/remove-wordpress-defaultmedia-image-sizes/

I even tried to achieve it by doing this

```
update_option( 'blog_feat_img', 720 );
```

but no matter what I do the theme is still loading my parent theme's `add_image_size()` values.

I've also written this following function to achieve this -

```
function img_update() {
    add_image_size( 'blog_feat_img', 720 );
    add_image_size( 'latest_posts_widget_feat_img', 400 );
    add_image_size( 'portfolio_widget_feat_img_1x', 400 );
    add_image_size( 'portfolio_widget_feat_img_2x', 800 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'img_update', 11 );
```

None of these is actually working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you regenerated the images using [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/screenshots/) or the like after the last bit of code? It should work.

Comment: Regenerated several times. :(

Comment: The problem is that `functions.php` file of child theme is loaded before parent's file, so you add the custom image sizes and afer that your parent theme overrides them. We need to know the action hook where the parent theme is adding the image sizes to see if it is possible to override them after it is done. Not always all options of a theme are reaady to be overriden by child themes; it depends on how the developer built the theme. Also, note that third party themes and plugins are off-topic and it maybe better if you ask to the developer.

Comment: Its ok. I figured it out at last :)

Comment: How did you do it? I have the same problem. The images are set in the parent theme with `add_image_size()`.

Comment: Try calling your custom image sizes with a lower priority value in the child theme rather than what it has in the parent theme. In this way the parent theme function will execute first then yours.

Comment: @Tamara did you fix it? how did you do it?

Comment: @iSaumya so you fixed it by changing priority value?

Comment: @TintinabulatorZea yes. It worked for me. But again had to dig into the parent theme to know what priority it is using.