# Change size and crop medium_large images

Tags: functions, hooks, post-thumbnails

I use events manager pro plugin to show an eventslist. These event-list is showing their thumbnail image in the new (wordpress 4.4) wordpress image size "medium_large" (width 768px). I need an image size of 600x255px which is cropped from the center.

How can i update these image size in my functions.php?

Answer (score 2):

According to what has been written in the documentation about responsive images in WP:

*https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/*

you should use `update_option` ([doc here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/)) to change size **medium_large** images

For example:

`update_option('medium_large_size_w',444)`

`update_option('medium_large_size_h',444)`

Answer (score 1):

You can call `add_image_size()` again to update the existing image size. Assuming it is called `medium_large` (Events Manager Pro is a paid plugin so not very much people have it) you can do something like:

```
<?php
function update_medium_large_size_wpse216595() {
    add_image_size( 'medium_large', 600, 255, array( 'center', 'top' ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'update_medium_large_size_wpse216595', 11 );
```

Then you will need to [regenerate the thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/). Although I am not 100% sure that `init` is the right hook for the job.

**p.s.** You can check [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74934/remove-or-update-add-image-size) if you are using a child theme.

**p.s.** 2. I am not sure that I understand the center cropping correctly. You many need to [play with it a bit](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/). `array( 'center', 'top' )` will crop the picture in the center ('trimming' the right and left part).

Comment: The `init`hook is not necessary, to early that cost of performance and time. You should use the hook `after_setup_theme`. This is the 'init' for run functions for the front end, the theme and should work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to update the image size with:

```
add_image_size( 'medium_large', 600, 255, array( 'center', 'top' ) );
```

But when i update the image size with height, width and crop, wordpress is just using the "large" image-size. When i just use add_image_size with the width argument:

```
add_image_size('medium_large', 600, '', true);
```

The image size gets updatet to 600px. Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get image to specific size, first you must add image size

```
add_image_size( 'medium_large', 600, 255, array( 'center', 'top' ) );
```

You have already upload image before add image size code, You must be regenerate image. You can use [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin.