# Prevent Wordpress from generating medium_large 768px size of image uploads?

Tags: images, media, library

I prevent WordPress from generating  `thumbnail`, `medium`, and `large` image sizes for images I upload to the Media Library, by setting their dimensions to `0` from the dashboard: `Settings -> Media` panel.

I have also gotten rid of all instances of `add_image_size` and `set_post_thumbnail_size` from the `functions.php` file of my theme.

However, when I upload new images, WordPress is still generating a `768px` width version (called 'medium_large') from my original full size image.  I believe it has something to do with [this update](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/).

Is there is any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You do realize that WordPress does this to reduce server load and speed up your site, right?

Comment: You are correct. The `medium_large` image size appeared in WordPress 4.4, together with responsive images feature. It has fixed width `768` px, and proportional height. This is hard coded into WordPress, unlike the other *default* image sizes. I also am removing it, however WordPress and other themes may rely on having this image size available to work properly. Keep this in mind if you ever need to switch to a default WordPress theme temporarily for debugging, or when trying new themes. If the size wasn't generated at image upload, other themes will not *automatically* generate it when needed

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216595/change-size-and-crop-medium-large-images

Answer (score 21):

To remove the `medium_large` image size you can try to remove it with the  [`intermediate_image_sizes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/intermediate_image_sizes/) filter:

```
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes', function( $sizes )
{
    return array_filter( $sizes, function( $val )
    {
        return 'medium_large' !== $val; // Filter out 'medium_large'
    } );
} );
```

Not sure if you're trying to remove all the intermediate sizes, but then you could try out:

```
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes', '__return_empty_array', 999 );
```

where [`__return_empty_array`()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__return_empty_array/) is a built-in core function.

We should note that it's not possible to remove it with

```
remove_image_size( 'medium_large' );
```

because it's not added with `add_image_size()` and therefore not part of the  `$_wp_additional_image_sizes` global array or `wp_get_additional_image_sizes()`;

Comment: yes it's also possible to change  the `medium_large_size_w` option to `0`, but we can't do it via `/wp-admin/options.php` because it seems to have problem with a 0 value there (that's actually what I tried first before writing the answer ;-), so we need to set it via settings API or manually in the `wp_options` table.

Answer (score 10):

Remove image size the same way wordpress core code does it:

```
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes', function($sizes) {
    return array_diff($sizes, ['medium_large']);
});
```

Keep in mind that `medium_large` is generally a good size to have in `srcset`, only remove it if you have understanding how `srcset` works, if you have similar sizes there already.

Answer (score 3):

this will work

```
function paulund_remove_default_image_sizes( $sizes) {
    unset( $sizes['medium_large']);
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced','paulund_remove_default_image_sizes');
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/intermediate_image_sizes_advanced/

Comment: While this did not create the image itself it did however create the entry in the attachment array, so a fake entry with the 769x at the end of the url. Using the default filder intermediate_image_sizes did get rid of making the image and not showing an entry for it in the array.